# getting jquery mobile click/tap event to trigger android native event

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile

i am a newbie to jquery mobile in android,using it for my app's animated menu every thing is working fine, open links on tap,but the problem is that how can i trigger my native android events on my jquery menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you would need to create your own phonegap plugin for your native android event...

I've added a link to an article I thought might be of some help...

[Extending Phonegap with Native Plugins for Android](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/extending-phonegap-with-native-plugins-for-android.html)